# JExcelApi - File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, android-studio, excel

Estoy usando JExcelAPI para lectura de Excel (.xls) pero estoy recibiendo el error

```
I/System.out: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\ElGra\OneDrive\Android_QuizGame\app\src\main\res\raw\output.xls (No such file or directory)
```

por lo que no funciona mi codigo.

```
package com.example.android_quizgame;


import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.List;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<String> preguntaIndex = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> preguntas = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> opcionCorrecta = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> opcionesA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> opcionesB = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> opcionesC = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> opcionesD = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> respuestas = new ArrayList<>();




String filepath = "C:\\Users\\ElGra\\OneDrive\\Android_QuizGame\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\output.xls";


    public void directorio(){
        File inputWorkbook = new File("C:\\Users\\ElGra\\OneDrive\\Android_QuizGame\\app\\src\\main\\res\\raw\\output.xls");
        Workbook w;
        try {
            System.out.println("ENTRANDO A DIRECTORIO()");
            w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputWorkbook);
            Sheet S = w.getSheet(0);

            for(int i=0; i< S.getRows() ; i++){
                for(int f = 0; f< S.getColumns(); f++){
                    Cell Z = S.getCell(f,i);
                    String XX = Z.getContents();
                    if(f==0){
                        preguntaIndex.add(XX);
                    }
                    else if(f==1){
                        preguntas.add(XX);
                    }
                    else if(f==2){
                        opcionCorrecta.add(XX);
                    }
                    else if(f==3){
                        System.out.println(XX);
                        opcionesA.add(XX);
                    }
                    else if(f==4){
                        System.out.println(XX);
                        opcionesB.add(XX);
                    }
                    else if(f==5){
                        opcionesC.add(XX);
                        System.out.println(XX);

                    }
                    else if(f==6){
                        opcionesD.add(XX);
                        System.out.println(XX);
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("VACIO");
                    }
                }
            }
            w.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }


    public String impresionPreg(){

        if(preguntas.isEmpty())
            return "VACIO";
        else
            return(preguntas.get(1));

    }
    public String printOpcA(){
        if(opcionesA.isEmpty())
            return "VACIO";
        else
            return opcionesA.get(1);

    }
    public String printOpcB(){
        if(opcionesB.isEmpty())
            return "VACIO";
        else
            return opcionesB.get(1);

    }
    public String printOpcC(){
        if(opcionesC.isEmpty())
            return "VACIO";
        else
            return opcionesC.get(1);

    }
    public String printOpcD(){
        if(opcionesD.isEmpty())
            return "VACIO";
        else
            return opcionesD.get(1);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


        directorio();



        TextView textoPreg = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        RadioButton opcA = findViewById(R.id.radioButton4);
        RadioButton opcB = findViewById(R.id.radioButton3);
        RadioButton opcC = findViewById(R.id.radioButton2);
        RadioButton opcD = findViewById(R.id.radioButton);

        textoPreg.setText(impresionPreg());
        opcA.setText(printOpcA());
        opcB.setText(printOpcB());
        opcC.setText(printOpcC());
        opcD.setText(printOpcD());

    }
}
```

Agradeceria su ayuda para solucionarlo
La plataforma es Android Studio.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a stackoverflow. El mensaje de excepción es porque el archivo o el directorio **no se encuentra en la ubicación o simplemente no existe.** ¿Has intentado cambiarlo a algún otro directorio?

Answer (score 0):

Ponlo en una ubicacion donde no esté tu OneDrive, quizás sea quien le moleste al Path. El problema está o bien en tu directorio o bien en tu fichero. 
-Cuando escribes en un fichero, da igual que no exista, lo crea (al menos con las librerías que uso yo en Java)
-Para leer un fichero debes tener el fichero creado de antes.

Por lo tanto, deduzco que si lo que te falla es el fichero, lo más probable sea que no existe el de lectura. Si no, juraría que es debido al Path.

Prueba a sacar el Path de OneDrive y a comprobar que el fichero de lectura está donde debe a ver qué pasa.